# assembly program for Fibonacci

Tags: assembly, fibonacci, risc

I just got a question about the assembly program for Fibonacci sequence. The question is as following :
The Fibonacci sequence `F` is defined as `F(1) = F(2) = 1` and for `n ≥ 2`,
`F(n + 1) = F(n) + F(n − 1)`
i.e., the `(n + 1)th` value is given by the sum of the `nth` value and the `(n − 1)th` value.

1. Write an assembly program typical of RISC machines for computing the `kth` value `F(k)`, where `k` is a natural number greater than `2` loaded from a memory location `M`, and storing the result at memory location `M`.

I received the answer of following:

```
   LOAD r2, M
   LOAD r0, #1
   LOAD r1, #1

4: SUB r2, r2, #1
   ADD r3, r0, r1
   LOAD r0, r1
   LOAD r1, r3
   BNE 4, r2, #2 // jump to instruction 4 if r2 is not equal to 2

   STOR M, r1
```

where # indicates immediate addressing and BNE stands for "branch if not equal".

I do not understand why... Can anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: Looks totally normal to me: keep the last 2 Fib(i) values around in registers to calculate the next one from.  If they'd unrolled the loop, you could `x += y` / `y += x`, but with it rolled up you need 2 register-copy instructions.  e.g. like this C version: [What's wrong with my MIPS code about finding fibonacci number?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43290402).

Comment: With 3 changes, the codr could handle M >= 0:  | LOAD r0,#-1 | LOAD r1,#1 | ... | BNE 4, r2, #-1 | . This is based on Fib(-2) = -1, Fib(-1) = 1, Fib(0) = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is perfectly correct. Here is a commented version that may answer your questions.

```
   LOAD r2, M     ; R2 -> k (as F(K) has to be computed)
   LOAD r0, #1    ; F(1)=1 -> r0 
   LOAD r1, #1    ; F(2)=1 -> r1 
                  ; As F(1) and F(2) are already computed, we start at i=2
                  ; During al the computation of F(i) r1==F(i-1) and r0== F(i-2)

4: SUB r2, r2, #1 ; k-- 
   ADD r3, r0, r1 ; F(i)=F(i-2)+F(i-1)
                  ; F(i) computed, prepare next iteration (implicitely i++)
   LOAD r0, r1    ; F(i-2)=r1 (previously F(i-1))
   LOAD r1, r3    ; F(i-1)=r3 (just computed F(i))
   BNE 4, r2, #2 // jump to instruction 4 if r2 (k) is not equal to 2
                  ; because we have started at i==2 we must perform
                  ; k-2 iterations. 
   STOR M, r1
```

Note that i never appears, but it is simpler to think of it, instead of k that is decremented.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alain!Can you please explain why it loads r2 to M?Can we not start with r0 and load it to M?Also I am not quite get what sub r2 r2 #1 means.Do you mind explaining it ?Thanks!

Comment: First line is just a mean to store in a register the value of k we want. Call it k or M, it does not matter, but we need to get this parameter. `sub r2, r2, #1` is sub(stract) 1 from r2 and store it in r2 and corresponds to r2<-r2-1.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alain. Does that mean if I store r0 to M will be ok? Not necessarily r2 to M?So for example, we can do  LOAD r0, M     
   LOAD r1, #1    
   LOAD r2, #1 ?

Comment: If you want you can do  LOAD r9, M LOAD r3, #1 LOAD r7, #1 The reg names do not matter, but you must be coherent. Think of regs as variables in C code. You can use whatever name, but keep the same all over a program.

Comment: I think my another question  is why subtract 1 from r2?

Comment: Exact C translation of asm code is:
`M=k;
f_2=1;
f_1=1;
do{
  k--;
  f=f_1+f_2;
  f_2=f_1;
  f_1=f;
} while(k>2);
result=f-1; // or f`
Without `k--`, you do not exit your loop.

Comment: The extract C is not what I am looking for. I am just trying to understand why the final answer in the paper is as what I wrote in the question. I still not quite understand why   ADD r3, r0, r1 ; F(i)=F(i-2)+F(i-1)
                  ; F(i) computed, prepare next iteration (implicitely i++)
   LOAD r0, r1    ; F(i-2)=r1 (previously F(i-1))
   LOAD r1, r3    ; F(i-1)=r3 (just computed F(i))

Comment: My thought is   r0 is 1 and r1 is 1. Why it suddenly turns to  ADD r3, r0, r1 ; F(i)=F(i-2)+F(i-1) ( r0=F(i-2) and r1=F(i-1))? <---- why is that?When did we change the r0 to F(i-2) and r1 to F(i-1)?)

Comment: Also why we can not just skip the  LOAD r0, r1    ; F(i-2)=r1 (previously F(i-1))
   LOAD r1, r3    ; F(i-1)=r3 (just computed F(i))  and just change Store M, r3?